# How to upload files to schemastore.org/json

Tags: json, jsonschema

Does anyone know how I can upload JSON schema files to schemastore.org?

http://schemastore.org/json/

Perhaps I submit a PR to: https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can file a PR to https://github.com/schemastore/schemastore/ as they propose in [Contribute](http://schemastore.org/json/#contribute) section.

> The goal of this API is to include schemas for all commonly known JSON file formats. To do that we encourage contributions in terms of new schemas, modifications and test files.
>
> SchemaStore.org is owned by the community and we have yet to turn down a pull request. Even if you're new to JSON Schemas, please submit new schemas anyway. We have many contributors that will help turn the schemas into perfection.